# memoir class, putting figures on empty pages before chapters

Tags: memoir

For a book project I'm using the memoir class :

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,
               openright,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
```

which leaves blank left pages in order to let chapters start on the right.

Question: Is there a way to put a figure on those empty page inserted automatically by memoir?
I have a problem to put a figure on the page between table of content and first chapter.

Comment: Putting `\begin{figure}[p]...\end{figure}` right before `\chapter` works fine, assuming there is an empty page to fill.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `\cleartooddpage` macro provide by `memoir`.

```
% figchapprob.tex  SE 567338
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\cleartooddpage[\vfill \begin{center} FIGURE \end{center} \vfill]
\chapter{First}

\cleartooddpage[\thispagestyle{plain}\vfill \begin{center} ANOTHER FIGURE \end{center} \vfill]
\chapter{Second}

\end{document}
```

With the `openright` option `memoir` starts a chapter with a `\cleardoublepage` which puts the chapter title on an odd page. The `cleartooddpage[<text>]` is similar in moving to an odd page except that it puts `<text>` on an otherwise blank even page.

A couple of examples of putting a figure at the center of the normally blank page before a chapter are shown; modify to your taste.

Comment: Peter, thank you very much for answering.
However: It works for any of my 17 chapters - except the first.
Best, Peter

Comment: It works also in front of the first chapter if I put \cleartooddpage... before \mainmatter, but only with text not with a figure. I'm using the graphicx package.

Comment: OK, done: Figure before \mainmatter but without \moveto... works.